# cakePHP Different routing for different User roles using LoginRedirect

Tags: php, cakephp

I am relatively new to cakePHP and the MVC approach aswell, and I might have a problem with regards to the design choice of my Models,views and controllers.. The application requires 3 different user roles : Admin, Staff, and Donors.  Currently, I have the admin set up, where he/she logs in and the loginRedirect is set as follows :

```
'loginRedirect' => array(
        'controller' => 'donors',
        'action' => 'index'
 ),
```

Now I have stumbled on this post :
[Multiple log in as per role in cakephp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912519/multiple-log-in-as-per-role-in-cakephp)

The Donors controller is sort of the main controller which the app revolves around, meaning that almost all the views rendered would belong to the Donors Controller. With this in mind, should I follow what was said on the post  : [Multiple log in as per role in cakephp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912519/multiple-log-in-as-per-role-in-cakephp)

If so, is my setup correct? I have the 'users' controller,model and views which takes care of all that stuff related to register, login and logout.
And I also have the Donor mvc structure aswell as its assosciated models.

How do i got about achieving that multi user-login, aswell as display different views of the Donor Controller according to the user role ?

------EDIT-------

The donor's index action is set to show all donor records, but I only want this for the admin/clerk users.. The donor user needs to have a different view upon logging in. Therefore I am confused as to whether there is a way to redirect the user to different views, or if I need to make my views render differently according to the user role! What are the possibilities? And what is the best practice?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17809170/logging-in-using-different-user-roles-in-cakephp

Comment: Have you checked this link?

Comment: @Anubhav Not before you pointed me towards it! Now I have gone through it ,and am currently reading on routing, as it seems that I require to know at least the basics of the routing configs in cake. As I also was having trouble with the way the url will be constructed. For ex. 
admin/users/login and staff/users/login... which is also addressed in the link you provided, if I understood correctly